# Compare host name from array of URLs and get unique values

Tags: php, arrays, unique, distinct

I need to compare URLs and remove duplicates from array but I want compare only host from url. I need skip http and https and www and others like last slash when I compare.
So when I have array:

```
    $urls = array(
'http://www.google.com/test', 
'https://www.google.com/test',
'https://www.google.com/example', 
'https://www.facebook.com/example',
'http://www.facebook.com/example');
```

Result will be only

```
http://www.google.com/test
http://www.google.com/example
http://www.facebook.com/example
```

I tried to compare like :

```
$urls = array_udiff($urls, $urls, function ($a, $b) {
                 return strcmp(preg_replace('|^https?://(www\\.)?|', '', rtrim($a,'/')), preg_replace('|^https?://(www\\.)?|', '', rtrim($b,'/')));
            });
```

But it return me empty array.

Comment: Maybe add the regex tag.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)

Comment: but where can You show me working example or any idea?

Comment: I need compare without www and need array of selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
   $urls = array(
    'http://www.google.com/test',
    'https://www.google.com/test',
    'https://www.google.com/example',
    'https://www.facebook.com/example',
    'http://www.facebook.com/example');


$MyArray = [];
for($i=0;$i<count($urls);$i++)  {

preg_match_all('/www.(.*)/', $urls[$i], $matches);

    if (!in_array($matches[1], $MyArray))
        $MyArray[] = $matches[1];
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($MyArray);
echo "</pre>";
```

And the output is

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => google.com/test
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => google.com/example
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => facebook.com/example
        )

)
```

trimmed and keeping only the host name

Comment: I updeted my question. I need compare all with hostname and all after hostname for example http://www/google.com/test I need check if in array I have google.com/test and if I have thid duplicates then remove Your code works great but I need compare with all landing page all after hostname

Comment: I updated my Answer with a new regex. If it works for you please accept it.

Comment: it si still not the same i need remove all before domain name. I tried somethink like |^https?://(www\\.)?|

Comment: before the hostname the "google , facebook" etc everyting is removed. all http:// is removed and started from the domain name and on. Check the output i have put here and provide with the output you would like to see.

Comment: I saw your update in the array example sand updated also my Array. From your description it is exactly what you need. keep the domain and after and compare all the rest.

Comment: ok but it return me my urls without early http and www i need to have this urls like in begginign but only remove duplicates

Comment: Your code works great but I need only compare my values and result need have htttp or https on start if url had it in first array Your result cut my scheme like http or www from urls I need only cut this to compare and then compare without this and then return distinct urls but with http www or something like in beggining

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach :

```
<?php
function parseURLs(array $urls){
    $rs = [];
    foreach($urls as $url){
        $segments = parse_url($url);
        if(!in_array($segments['host'], $rs))
            $rs[] = $segments['host'];
    }
    return $rs;
}
```

Then :

```
<?php
$urls = array(
    'http://www.google.com',
    'https://www.google.com',
    'https://www.google.com/',
    'https://www.facebook.com',
    'http://www.facebook.com'
);
$uniqueURLs = parseURLs($urls);
print_r($uniqueURLs);

/* result :
Array
(
    [0] => www.google.com
    [1] => www.facebook.com
)
*/
```

Comment: I have one more question what if I want compare hostanme with path for example http://www.google.com/test and want compare only google.com/test ?

Comment: basically we use [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) for extracting the url, this function returning path as well. Just modify the parseURLS fn little bit to check the path value as well. [here](https://gist.github.com/tajhulfaijin/a623772931919886d9ea2cc9b84e90cd)

Answer (score 0):

You need to Loop through the URL's, Parse URL with PHP's `url_parse()` function and use array_unique to remove duplicates from array, so we are checking both the host and path ..

I have written a class for you:

```
<?php
/** Get Unique Values from array Values **/
Class Parser {
    //Url Parser Function
    public function arrayValuesUrlParser($urls) {
        //Create Container
        $parsed = [];
        //Loop Through the Urls
        foreach($urls as $url) {
            $parse = parse_url($url);
            $parsed[] = $parse["host"].$parse["path"];
            //Delete Duplicates
            $result = array_unique($parsed);
        }
        //Dump result
        print_r($result);
    }

}

?>
```

Using the Class

```
<?php
//Inlcude tghe Parser
include_once "Parser.php";

    $urls = array(
    'http://www.google.com/test', 
    'https://www.google.com/test',
    'https://www.google.com/example', 
    'https://www.facebook.com/example',
    'http://www.facebook.com/example');
    //Instantiate
    $parse = new Parser();
    $parse->arrayValuesUrlParser($urls);

?>
```

You can do it in one file if you don't need to seperate files but you will have to remove include_once if you are using one php file. This class is also on PHP Classes, did it for fun !

Best of Luck !

Comment: what if I want compare landing page my question was update

Comment: You simply concatenate this .$parse["path"];  I have updated the class ..

Comment: it look great bu what if there will be query after path. And second think it take this www. I have sometimes urls without www

Comment: I need get only google.com/test or google.com/everythinkwhatwillbewroteafterthisslash to compare my urls

Comment: You can simply remove the ["scheme"] from the result, then use str_replace() to remove the www par or alternatively use preg_match(), sorry I'm at work but i you haven't found an answer will help you in the evining ..